# Upgrading Fedora Server to 37, Postgres' upgrade didn't work: ERROR: could not access file "$libdir/postgis-3"

Tags: postgresql, fedora, upgrade, postgis

After everything else was shown to be working fine (YAY!), `Postgres` refused to start (don't be thrown by the name - Postgres was packaged as `PostgreSQL` in praise of Paul Aoki's conversion of the `QUEL` query language processor to use `SQL` WAY back in the first packaged release in 1995 - everything but the packaging/branding uses the name `Postgres`).

This failure to start was not unexpected, though the package COULD have anticipated this for upgrades, since all upgraded installations likely have a need to do this, and run the appropriate upgrade script for us; that script can be run thus:

```
postgresql-setup --upgrade --upgrade-from postgresql
```

Unfortunately, it failed.

I followed the trail of error bread-crumbs - a log file in the `Postgres` user's home directory, pointed to by an intermediate log that's spit out to `stdout` by said command, pointed to an issue with `Postgis`, which is used by the installation.

The most pertinent error message said:

```
ERROR:  could not access file "$libdir/postgis-3"
```

Unfortunately, it didn't say where `$libdir` is supposed do be, and equally unfortunately, I don't know where it is, either! I haven't yet found any directory containing the name `postgis`.

I presumed `Postgis` was not upgraded or perhaps not installed, but that proved incorrect with a simple check of installed packages: It's called `postgis-3.2.2-1.fc37.x86_64`

As the error message had complained about not finding a part of `postgis-3` and yet a `postgis` version 3 is installed was a surprise to me.

I have no fix yet. Thoughts? This MUST be a common problem for `Postgres` users who also use `Postgis`!

Answer (score 1):

[PostGIS](https://postgis.net/) is an extension which is installed as package. You have to install the package that suits both your postgresql major version and postgis extension version. Such as; `postgis32_15` or `postgis31_14`

`$libdir` or any other predefined (mostly comes with compilation) configurations can be learned with [pg_config](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pgconfig.html) client application. You can basically learn **libdir** by running the command below.

```
pg_config --pkglibdir
```

if you cannot find **pg_config** then its most propably where **psql** command is (`$bindir`) .

Comment: Good information and that sounds good but unfortunately, it isn't sufficient in my case as I DID already have the PostGIS package installed - after all, it's now a part of my template1 db! However, I can see that this might well solve the problem for some people. So, if anyone comments here that this worked for them, I'll mark it as "the answer" unless one that works for ME comes along! (Note: To get going now, I ran dumpall in the old version and reloaded in the new one and that worked flawlessly. Still, I'd like a genuine solution to this as I was lucky the installation was small!)

Answer (score 0):

On Fedora 37, you get this error error message during the db upgrade if you haven't installed the `postgis-upgrade` package.

Thus, the complete upgrade procedure for postgis enabled databases is something like this:

```
systemctl start postgresql.service
# => start fails fails and some hints are logged
dnf install postgresql-upgrade postgis-upgrade
postgresql-setup --upgrade
systemctl start postgresql.service
sudo -u postgres psql -f /var/lib/pgsql/update_extensions.sql
sudo -u postgres reindexdb yourdb
```

In general, it's a good idea to review the upgrade logs (and the standard `/var/lib/pgsql/data/log/postgresql*.log`) in case there are some extra hints, specific to your concrete database.